# Unique 1000 records with 6 digits

Tags: php

I am using this code to generate 1000 records with 6 numbers each but i want unique records.
Is my way the right way?

```
<?php

for ($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++)
   {
    echo "<br>";
    echo str_pad(mt_rand(0, 999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);   
   }

?>
```

Comment: Your way is fine, but you don't check for duplicate records

Comment: Use an array and loop until it fills up to 1000 with unique numbers.

Comment: Just count from `100000` to `100999` ;) Each of those numbers has 6 digits and is unique. *edit:* You might want to describe your requirements better.

Comment: @FelixKling i give you +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$numbers = array();
while (count($numbers)<1000) {
    $numbers[] = str_pad(mt_rand(0, 999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);  
    $numbers = array_unique($numbers); 
}
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow, calling `array_unique()` and `count()` one thousand times... Could this be more inefficient?

Comment: You can generate an array with, let's say, 1100 numbers, run array_unique and take the first 1000 numbers from the array.

Comment: You still have the possibility of not generating 1000 unique numbers, and now you've generated 100 more numbers than you needed to.

Comment: Or you can generate 1000 numbers, run array_unique, and supply additional numbers with the above code if there are any duplicates.

Comment: "supply additional numbers" is still inefficient - Can you think of an approach where your `$numbers` array never contains more than 1000 numbers, never contains duplicates, all while running in `O(n)` time?